# Deploying an ear with web.xml on websphere changes the web.xml or create web_merged.xml with changed attributes for multi-part

Tags: servlets, websphere, web.xml

I have an ear file built which has a war file inside.The war has `web.xml` which has servlet defined:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExcelDownload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web.ExcelDownload</servlet-class>
    <multipart-config>
        **<!--<max-file-size>1048576</max-file-size> -->**
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

The problem here is my in ear file `max-file-size` is commented that means there are no attributes defined for the multipart-config. But when I deploy my ear on WebSphere 8.5.5.9, it changes my `web.xml` to:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExcelDownload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ofss.infra.web.ExcelDownload</servlet-class>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>0</max-file-size>
        **<max-request-size>0</max-request-size>**
        <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

Since the `max-file-size` attribute is defined as zero in `web.xml` I am not not able to use HTTP request to upload the file to server.

I need help on to understand why the attribute is being added by WAS though its not available in ear. I did my digging I tried during deployment not to use metadata-complete attribute to false then instead of changing `web.xml` WAS has created a new file `web_merged.xml` (this has `max-file-size` set to zero) and am still facing the issue.

Comment: kumar Have you found why it happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: Dear ... i raised this issue with IBM WAS team through the license we have in our bank and the IBM team gave a fix not to auto populate the max file size value to 0 as it’s not available in web.xml of my application and also as per multiconfig the default value should be -1 in case no value is available so they fixed it